# A'C+AB - can it be simplified?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I had a really big expression that i've simplified to:A'C+AB. I just wanted to check with everyone that it can't be simplified any further. There's no trick to factor out the A' and A is there?

In general, how do you know whether you've got the simplest expression? I'm new to Boolean algebra and am not sure how I will know when I've simplified an expression to it's simplest form.

Comment: It seems that $A'C + AB$ is already in a minimal form. I'm quite sure that you can't do better. I'm also quite sure that there is a theorem asserting this.

Comment: If your problem doesn't include many variables, with proper use of Karnaugh Map, you may guarantee that your expression cannot be further simplified. Here, you can find more information about Karnaugh Maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Thanks guys. Looked into Karnaugh maps yesterday. Quite interesting!